# Problem in adding Customer in shopify using api

Tags: api, shopify

I have a shopify store and I have created a custom form in footer of my store and want to use details added from that form to create a new customer. I have tried to send a post request to endpoint "/admin/customers.json" using code given below

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.klaviyo_submit_button').on('click', function(){

    $.ajax({
            url: '/admin/customers.json',
            dataType: 'json',
            type: 'POST',
            data:{
                   "customer": {
                      "first_name": "Steve",
                      "last_name": "Lastnameson",
                      "email": "steve.lastnameson@example.com",
                      "phone": "+15142546011",
                      "verified_email": true    
                 }
            },
            success: function() {
              alert('Customer is added');
            }
          });
    })

})
```

But it is not sending post request and shows status code "303 see other". Can someone please let me know what mistake I made here and how can I add customer from this form. I am using this code in shopify's theme.js.liquid file.

Thanks

Comment: Do you have any admin credentials with write permissions for customers that you're using to make that request?

Comment: I am doing this in same shopify code so where do I need permission?

Comment: You're hitting a `/admin` endpoint  - normal users floating around the Internet don't have permission to do anything that an `admin` would!  To make that call work, you need an app with the appropriate permissions to make the call on the user's behalf.  Well, that or expose credentials in your code to give random internet people the power to read & write to /customers. The latter is a pretty sizeable security hole to open up - either use native forms if you can or make a secure app to do the heavy lifting for you.

Answer (score 3):

You do not add customers to your Shop from the front end using Javascript calls to /admin. That would mean you'd be exposing App API keys to the public. Instead, Shopify provides you with forms that customers fill in, and they get submitted to the shop and processed securely.

If you insist on adding customers with your own forms, you can setup an App, with permissions to add customers, then use the App Proxy pattern to send the form to the App to create the customers. That is secure, and works.

Comment: If we can't add customers from my way without using app then how are we able to add, update product and cart contents by using ajax in same code?

Comment: What is this 303 see others error meaning can someone explain with example?

Comment: Adding items to the cart has ZERO to do with /admin/customers. No protection needed. A public JS API meant for cart add/update/delete is available. So what? I answered your question. You can at least thank me.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot create new customer record submitting post data on admin/customers.json directly with public access. Even though your complete requirement is not clear from detail shared by you, I suggest here two solutions.

**Solution 1**: Use account creation form to create new record `<form method="post" action="/account" id="create_customer" accept-charset="UTF-8">`.

**Solution 2**: Create a custom App in your store and submit your data to a script(you can use PHP) hosted on server which will create a record using Customer API.

Step 1: Go to Apps tab in admin section of your store. Scroll down and click on **Manage private apps**, create an App here to generate API keys and password.

Step 2: Create and host(on a secured server) a script that will use API keys generated in previous step to create new customer record using https://help.shopify.com/en/api/reference/customers/customer#create

Step 3: Create a form on website and submit your form using Ajax to script in step 2. A new customer record will be created in your store.

Note: *You can test this API by using credential created in Step 1 on Postmen tool you can refer https://help.shopify.com/en/api/reference/customers/customer#create*. You will have to hit **Example URL** generated in Private app from Step 1.